# The smooth atlas of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold with an atlas $A$, and $p$ is a point of $M$. pick a smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ such that $p \in U$, then a trick we often use is that we can always let $\phi(p) = 0$. The reason is that if $\phi(p) \neq 0$, we can simply compose it with a translation map.

My question is, if we do compose it with a translation map, how am I able to guarantee that this composition is still in the original atlas $A$? If it is not in $A$, then how am I able to conclude that this change of charts will not have any impact on the structure of $M$?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the atlas. But you can extend the atlas to a maximal atlas, a union of all atlases belonging to the smooth structure it generates. In particular, composition of any map in the atlas with a diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$ can be safely "added". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_structure#Maximal_smooth_atlases

Comment: @PeterFranek That looks like an answer to me ...

Comment: @PeterFranek, that is certainly true. But my concern is if I am trying to prove certain theorem and will it change the result if I use something that is not originally in my atlas $A$ but is still within the smooth structure of $M$(which is the maximal atlas)?

Comment: @Keith Depends on the theorem. If it is concerned with one particular atlas (I have never seen such theorem in diff.top.), then it could play a role. If it is a statement about the smooth manifold, then not. But this you probably have known already...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handwavey:  Translation is invertible.

More formally, you may replace your atlas $A$ with the extended atlas $A \cup \{\text{this translated version of $(U,\phi)$}\}$.  It is easy to show that this translated version of $(U,\phi)$ is compatible with $(U,\phi)$ (because translation is invertible) and then that it is compatible with the rest of the atlas.  This means appending this chart does not change the manifold.

Using more machinery, you could argue that each maximal atlas containing your original atlas contains the translated version of $(U,\phi)$.  (Once again, the invertibility of translation is important.)